# Android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

Android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin

> android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin. 
>   Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead.
>   Affected Modules: app

what i miss!
this my gradle Modules app

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'realm-android'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.app.app"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        repositories {
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
        implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
        implementation 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
        annotationProcessor 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
         compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4') {
            exclude module: 'okhttp'
        }
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.1.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.1'
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
         implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
        implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:9.0.1'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    }
```

Comment: What is your Android Gradle plugin version?

Comment: my gradle Plugin version is 3.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below line in dependencies block :

```
     annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
```